# How can I convert a numpy array of tensors to tensor of tensors?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

It is my first GRU model so pardon the stupidity. I am trying to learn by training a simple GRU network on variable length sequences. The sequences are numpy arrays of tensors. The length of numpy array varies from sample to sample.

The model generator and fit code is below:

```
def declare_model(emb_size, gru_size, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, emb_size))
    gru_out = keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.GRU(gru_size, return_sequences=False))(inputs)
    gru_out = keras.layers.Flatten()(gru_out)
    predictions = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')(gru_out)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
m = declare_model(emb_size=200, gru_size=20, num_classes=2)
m.fit(dafr["Data"], dafr["Label"], epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
```

The type of an element of 'dafr["Data"]' is "numpy.ndarray" type of each element of this element is "torch.Tensor" shape of each tensor is "200 {torch. Size([200])}" and dtype of tensor is float. Type of element of 'dafr["Label"]' is 'numpy.int64'. While fitting I am getting error "ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).". Why is this error occurring and how can I resolve it?
I can successfully attain the task if I pad all samples to same length but I donot want to do that.

Comment: Normally `keras/tensorflow` expects data that's consistent in shape/length.  All your errors revolve around trying to make a multidimensional array with a float or int dtype, or the tensor equivalent.  Your "variable length sequences" is inconsistent with this model.  Either fix the data, or find a different model that can handle variable lengths.  By the way, how of much of this is your own code, based on your own study of `tensorflow` docs, or is it copied off of some tutorial that you don't understand?

Comment: @hpaulj That's what I am confused about. I have already done classification of variable length sequence using rnn (Bi-GRU) but back then I used text vectorization layer, later I understood that that model will suffer from out of vocabulary words and to make things worse text vectorization layer just suppressed any errors. About the code, yes it is copied from a reference but it's just because I was lazy to type, I think I understand it.

Comment: For some reason, I keep trying to explain what might be wrong, without first insisting on seeing the FULL ERROR with traceback.  That should tell us - and you - what step in the code is trying to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the input arrays to tensors using tf.convert_to_tensor from TensorFlow library

```
    import tensorflow as tf
dafr["Data"] = tf.convert_to_tensor(dafr["Data"], dtype=tf.float32)
```

you can convert dafr["Label"] to a tensor as follows:

```
dafr["Label"] = tf.convert_to_tensor(dafr["Label"], dtype=tf.int64)
```

Comment: This gives "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.". Also, what was logic behind "dtype=tf.float32".